# Livewire has problem redirect to login page when session expired

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Livewire has problem redirect to login page when session expired.

I tried to click update button on livewire component when session expired.
Tab: console has error
Tab: network return status code 302 and redirect to login

but on frontend not redirect to login page

[image: Tab: console]

[image: Tab: network]

Please suggestion for this solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which version of Livewire are you using?

Comment: I use livewire version 2